# How to detect if a document update in Elasticsearch has failed

Tags: java, elasticsearch, updates

I'm updating a document in Elasticsearch using Java API and from time to time it fails without any indication (maybe 1 in 10). The only way I can see if the update has been successful is to read the document to check and see if it has been updated.

`IndexResponse` has a method called `isCreated` and as its name indicates, it only returns true if there's been a successful insertion. This method will return false on an update, regardless of it being successful or unsuccessful.

Here's my code to update a document:

```
IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(index_name, type_name, doc_id)
    .source(json);

UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest(index_name, type_name, doc_id)
    .doc(json)
    .upsert(indexRequest);

UpdateResponse response = es_client.update(updateRequest).actionGet();
```

Before I can fix the failed update, I need to detect if the request has been successful or not. But how?

P.S. `UpdateResponse` inherits from `IndexResponse` and has no extra method to indicate update's status, or at least to my knowledge.

Comment: I _think_ you need to GET the document and check it after the update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the UpdateResponse, you can retrieve a `ShardInfo` instance which contains the number of `failed` and `successful` shard operations. If `failed: 0`, odds are high that the operation succeeded.

```
int failed = response.getShardInfo().getFailed()
```

Comment: When the operation fails, `getShardInfo()` is like: `{"total":0, "successful":0, "failed":0}` but other times it's `{"total":2, "successful":1, "failed":0}`

Comment: Then `total: 0` is a good indication that no operation took place. For proper execution you should check that `total > 0` and `total == successful`

Comment: I believe `total` does not refer to the number of documents, instead something like the number of shards or something. I'm not sure. But I was updating only one document, not two!

Comment: Yes, `ShardInfo` represents... shard info. `total` is the number of shard operations, but as I said if `total > 0` and `total == successful` then it's a good indication that the update went ok.

Comment: Sorry, I've had to complete my sentence. In my case, `successful` is always `1` and `total` is always `2`! They never match even though the operation is successful. I think `total` counts number of shards and `successful` counts number of successful operations. And one document always resides in one shard, I think these two numbers are not comparable, or at least it's my understanding. Never experienced it, but maybe `successful` counts the number of replications with successful operation.